# Firebase functions deploy problem (Failed to create/update function)

Tags: firebase, function, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I would like to ask for the help of people familiar with Firebase functions. I am struggling with the problem that uploading the code via firebase cli fails. It was working a few days ago, I didn't change anything in the world, I mean through the configuration. And it gets stuck at a part where not even a code change was made. I have had this problem ever since the client set the editor role to the owner role. But in theory this shouldn't be a problem.

`firebase deploy --debug` returns this:

```
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Unable to retrieve the repository metadata for projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1/repositories/gcf-artifacts. Ensure that the Cloud Functions service account has 'artifactregistry.repositories.list' and 'artifactregistry.repositories.get' permissions. You can add the permissions by granting the role 'roles/artifactregistry.reader'.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

I set it up but it still doesn't work. Maybe in the wrong place or I don't know. I only encountered similar problems on the net, but none of them helped. I do not know what to do. Artifactregistry api is also enabled.

firebase functions:log :

```
2022-11-09T22:15:55.891760Z E friendRequestNotification: {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":7,"message":"Unable to retrieve the repository metadata for projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1/repositories/gcf-artifacts. Ensure that the Cloud Functions service account has 'artifactregistry.repositories.list' and 'artifactregistry.repositories.get' permissions. You can add the permissions by granting the role 'roles/artifactregistry.reader'."},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"{email}"},"requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"{ip}","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"FirebaseCLI/11.16.0,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)","requestAttributes":{"time":"2022-11-09T22:15:56.055987Z","auth":{}},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction","authorizationInfo":[{"resource":"projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1/functions/friendRequestNotification","permission":"cloudfunctions.functions.create","granted":true,"authorizationLoggingOptions":{"permissionType":"ADMIN_WRITE"},"resourceAttributes":{}}],"resourceName":"projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1/functions/friendRequestNotification","request":{"function":{"sourceUploadUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-760418412171.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/6d1f7217-7899-484f-911c-1dbcb4512d8d.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-{}@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires={}","labels":{"deployment-tool":"cli-firebase","firebase-functions-hash":"{hash}"},"runtime":"nodejs16","dockerRegistry":"ARTIFACT_REGISTRY","entryPoint":"friendRequestNotification","name":"projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1/functions/friendRequestNotification","eventTrigger":{"eventType":"providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create","resource":"projects/{projectname}/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}/friends/{friendId}"}},"location":"projects/{projectname}/locations/us-central1","@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest"},"resourceLocation":{"currentLocations":["us-central1"]}}
```

I have already tried all options within the Google cloud iam&admin settings, but nothing.

Comment: I had the same error today while trying Next.js SSR with Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, right. Got an issue.

```
PATCH https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/.../functions/... {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Unable to retrieve the repository metadata for projects/.../repositories/gcf-artifacts. Ensure that the Cloud Functions service account has 'artifactregistry.repositories.list' and 'artifactregistry.repositories.get' permissions. You can add the permissions by granting the role 'roles/artifactregistry.reader'.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

After updating the plan from Spark (Free) to Blaze (Pay as you go) - the following command started working again as expected.

```
    firebase deploy --debug --only functions
```

Answer (score 11):

Well, I solved the issue by updating my credit card. Basically, billing was disabled because my credit card was expired and all the permissions were disabled.

Comment: Same here, that was a very unhelpful error message.

Comment: It was the same for me. Had to add a new payment method and switch back again to Blaze plan.

Answer (score 5):

Try to enable the created artifacts for your project on Google Cloud Console
https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts